# Is it possible to create a Generic repository with SpringData?

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa, crud

I wonder how would it be possible to create a sort of generic repository like this

```
@Repository
public interface GenericApiDao<T> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer> {
    
}
```

Unfortunately I got this error message :

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericApiDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

Why don't we have the right to say to SpringData the type at the execution only ?

Thank you for your help ^^
Joss

Comment: Spring Data needs the type information to implement the repository interface and create (instantiate and initialize) the corresponding bean.